# Detection of 301 Redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx

In NGINX is there a way to detect is a site was accessed via a 301 redirect? An NGINX server was setup incorrectly and site B now has some 301 redirects cached in browsers pointing to site A. I would like to redirect these a second time to new site C from both A and B, but, only redirect from A if they were previously redirected from B to A and let users who directly access A get to A without redirect.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't detect that, no.

Browsers do not include HTTP status codes from previous responses in a new request. At most you get the previous URL in the `Refererer` header, but even that is unreliable (many users disable sending that header as it is seen as a security or privacy breach).

As such an HTTP server has no way of knowing if a request was initiated by a redirect, the user following a link